# How do I use the appengine/urlfetch package with goauth2?

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, go

The [goauth2](https://code.google.com/p/goauth2/) package has an example use. But on app engine, the normal http.Client isn't available. How do I use the app engine urlfetch package with goauth2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must add a `Transport` parameter to the first line of the callback:

```
t := &oauth.Transport{
    Config:    oauth_conf,
    Transport: &urlfetch.Transport{Context: c},
}
```